# How to verify the access token at nodejs express api retrieved from keycloak in a react SPA?

Tags: node.js, keycloak, single-page-application, openid-connect

I received an access token from keycloak in my react SPA but don't know how to use the same token in nodejs express backend API to verify if this is the valid token or not.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keycloak-connect`

```js
const Keycloak = require("keycloak-connect");
const keycloak = new Keycloak({});
appapp.use(keycloak.middleware());
```

and also you need `keycloak.json` in root like below

```json
{
  "clientId": "...",
  "bearerOnly": true,
  "serverUrl": "...",
  "realm": "...",
  "realmPublicKey": "..."
}
```